# Google API & OAuth2

Tags: c#, .net, google-api

Following Google code samples as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth).

I've replicated their code samples in a test project of my own (Using MVC 4 Template in Visual Studio Express 2013), I cannot run the project because I'm getting these errors:

> Error 1   Since 'Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4.Controllers.HomeController.IndexAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task'?    f:\users\sausages\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\GooglePOC\GooglePOC\Controllers\googleAnalytics.cs  33  17  GooglePOC
>
> Error 2   Since 'Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4.Controllers.HomeController.IndexAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task'?    f:\users\sausages\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\GooglePOC\GooglePOC\Controllers\googleAnalytics.cs  37  17  GooglePOC

This is the block of code it's complaining about:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Services;

using Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
                AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (result.Credential != null)
            {
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                    ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample"
                });

                // YOUR CODE SHOULD BE HERE..
                // SAMPLE CODE:
                var list = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
                ViewBag.Message = "FILE COUNT IS: " + list.Items.Count();
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Task` is pretty much the same as `void` but in an asynchronous context so it might be that it is complaining about that. Does it change if you return `Task<ViewResult>` instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The answer to the question which worked for me was to provide the type Task<ActionResult> (replacing Task<>) in the method definition, as I illustrated in the line of code.  Thought that answered the question 
(which I assumed to be "how can I make my code work?).